# Error in retrieving data from database using codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

is working good not an issue. if in case say for example the stored values is section_2 ok, later if i want it to update with section 1 then the section 1 is not displayed in the dropdown . i want to display section 1 as well as section 2, how i can fix the issue ?

```
<select name="type">
    <?php foreach($data as $row){ ?>
          <option value="<?php echo $row->ID ?>"><?php echo $row->type ?></option>
          <option value="Section_2">Section 2</option>
    <?php } ?>
</select>
```

Comment: where is your php code

Comment: i did not got u sir

Comment: show php (controller) code and write question with more details.

Comment: I mean this is only html code you need to post php code too .

Comment: you have to manually do if statements in options if they are selected. you can't just set the value. or you can use the form helper

Comment: ok sure sir i will update my question just a minute

Comment: `<select name="type">
                    <?php foreach($data as $row){ ?>
                    <option value="<?php echo $row->ID ?>"><?php echo $row->type ?></option>
                    <option value="Section_2">Section 2</option>
                    <?php } ?>
                </select>`   sir i tried like this and it worked is it proper way to do ? @RahulShrivastava @Alex @jagdeesh kumar

Comment: yes you can do something like this <select name="type" value="<?php echo $row->type; ?>">
    <option selected="true" disabled="disabled">Select an option</option>
    <?php foreach($data as $row){ ?> 
  <option value="<?php echo $row->ID; ?>">
   <?php echo $row->type; ?>
  </option> 
 <?php } ?>
</select>

Comment: but im facing one issue in it if in case the fetched data is section_2 na then it should display section_2 and as well as section_1  but here im getting fetched as section_2 correctly but i need section_1 also how can i do that ?

Comment: sir im facing this issue say the fetched values is section_2 then in case i want to update it to section_1then in dropdown list ony the fetched values is displayed. what changes i should do when i want to change it to section_1 @RahulShrivastava

Comment: @keerthipatil you need to update the question with the expected output.

Comment: sir i updated my question, the updated question is working good not an issue. if in case say for example the stored values is section_2 ok, later if i want it to update with section 1 then the section 1 is not displayed in the dropdown only ? i want to display section 1 as well as section 2, how i can fix the issue ?

Comment: sir please check my updated question sir

Comment: https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/176455/rahul

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
      <?php if(your_edit_value =='section_1'){?>
      <option value="section_1" selected>section_1</option>
      <?php } else {?>
      <option value="section_1">section_1</option>
      <?php if(your_edit_value =='Section_2'){?>
      <option value="Section_2" selected>Section 2</option>
      <?php }else { ?>
      <option value="Section_2">Section 2</option>
      <?php }?>
      </select>
```